# C# MongoDB Driver 2.2 Async Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I am relatively new to MongoDB CSharp driver. I haven't used Async methods previously. I have created an ASP.NET MVC project and I am using MongoDB to store the data. My Data repository resides in a totally separate project. I am getting the records as follows:

```
namespace PostBoard.Data 
{
  public class PostDataRepository 
  {

    private IMongoDatabase db = null;

    public PostDataRepository() 
    {

    }
    public PostDataRepository(IMongoDatabase mongoDb) 
    {
      db = mongoDb;

    }



    public IList<Post> GetAllPosts() 
    {
      List<Post> _postQueryable = GetAllPostsFromDb().Result;
      return _postQueryable;
    }

    public async Task<List<Post>> GetAllPostsFromDb() 
    {
      IMongoCollection<Post> _postCollection = db.GetCollection<Post> ("userpost");


      SortDefinitionBuilder<Post> sortBy = Builders<Post>.Sort;
      SortDefinition <Post> sort = sortBy.Descending(x => x.PostDate);
      Task <List<Post>> _postTask = await Task.FromResult<Task<List< Post>>> (_postCollection.Find <Post> (_ => true).Sort(sort).ToListAsync());

      return _postTask.Result;
    }
  }
}
```

I am calling the GetAllPosts function in my MVC Controller and it works fine. However, if I change the GetallPostsFromDb() (to something like following), it doesn't work.

```
public async Task <List<Post>> GetAllPostsFromDb() 
{
  IMongoCollection <Post> _postCollection = db.GetCollection <Post> ("userpost");


  SortDefinitionBuilder <Post> sortBy = Builders<Post>.Sort;
  SortDefinition<Post> sort = sortBy.Descending(x => x.PostDate);
  List <Post> _postTask = await _postCollection.Find <Post> (_ => true).Sort(sort).ToListAsync();

  return _postTask;
}
```

I have seen some examples and it seems the proper way to do it is the second variation but when I use it, my web pages seems to be stuck in 'waiting for reply' mode.

Comment: Can you edit to add how you're calling GetAllPostsFromDb() in your controller

Comment: I am not calling GetAllPostsFromDb in my controller. I am calling GetAllPostsFromDb().Result in the method above GetAllPosts() which is not async. and GetAllPosts is what gets called in the controller

Answer (score 0):

Make `GetAllPosts()` an async method and then await your call to `GetAllPostsFromDb()`. This will return a `List<Posts>` object.

```
public async IList<Post> GetAllPosts() 
{
    List<Post> _postQueryable = await GetAllPostsFromDb();
    return _postQueryable;
}
```

Comment: If I make this async, how can I then reference this in my MVC Controller? Should the MVC controller be async as well?